# How can I select rows that are null using bound queries in Perl's DBI?

Tags: sql, perl, dbi

I want to be able to pass something into an SQL query to determine if I want to select only the ones where a certain column is null.  If I was just building a query string instead of using bound variables, I'd do something like:

```
if ($search_undeleted_only)
{
    $sqlString .= " AND deleted_on IS NULL";
}
```

but I want to use bound queries.  Would this be the best way?

```
my $stmt = $dbh->prepare(...
    "AND (? = 0 OR deleted_on IS NULL) ");
$stmt->execute($search_undeleted_only);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; a related trick is if you have X potential filters, some of them optional, is to have the template say `" AND ( ?=-1 OR  some_field = ? ) "`, and create a special function that wraps the execute call and binds all the second ?s.  (in this case, -1 is a special value meaning 'ignore this filter').

Update from Paul Tomblin: I edited the answer to include a suggestion from the comments.

Comment: That's good, but put it the other way around (the ?=-1 part first), since many SQL databases where clauses short circuit (meaning, it won't bother evaluating the subsequent part of an OR statement if the first part is true since there's no way it will evaluate to anything but true).

Comment: I hope you guys don't mind, but I'm going to edit your answer to put the ?=-1 first just to make the answer better.

Comment: By the way, there is some really good information about the query optimization in Bill Karwin's answer.  I wish I could accept them both.

Answer (score 2):

So you're relying on short-circuiting semantics of boolean expressions to invoke your `IS NULL` condition?  That seems to work.

One interesting point is that a constant expression like `1 = 0` that did not have parameters should be factored out by the query optimizer.  In this case, since the optimizer doesn't know if the expression is a constant `true` or `false` until execute time, that means it can't factor it out.  It must evaluate the expression for every row.

So one can assume this add a minor cost to the query, relative to what it would cost if you had used a non-parameterized constant expression.

Then combining with `OR` with the `IS NULL` expression may also have implications for the optimizer.  It might decide it can't benefit from an index on `deleted_on`, whereas in a simpler expression it would have.  This depends on the RDBMS implementation you're using, and the distribution of values in your database.

Comment: @Bill, that's really great info about the query optimization, and I wish I could accept both yours and Dmitriy's answers.

Comment: No worries!  I'm glad it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's a reasonable approach. It follows the normal filter pattern nicely and should give good performance.